# Jax-ws client : very slow initialisation

Tags: java, performance, jax-ws

I'm trying to call a webservice with a JAX-WS generated proxy.

The WSDL is relatively small (11kB) with only 3 operations, and is stored locally.

But when I try to init the port, it gets stuck for 10-20 seconds on this line in stdout :

> Retrieving document at
>   'file:/C:/path/to/webapp/WebContent/WEB-INF/wsdl/'.

which corresponds to the `new MyServicePort(new URL(wsdlLocation))`, and reading of the wsdl.

All subsequent calls to the webservice work fine, and fast (<200 ms for each call).

Subsequent calls to `new MyServicePort(new URL(wsdlLocation))` are also fast...

Are such response times normal on a reasonably spec'ed computer? (core i5 + 8GB ram)

Comment: does that wsdl include schema imports which are remote urls?

Comment: no, there's no remote urls, except for namespaces

Comment: you should attach a profiler to see where it is taking it's time.  anything else is just guessing.

Comment: Did you find any answer for this question in the meantime?

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first Web-service calls are usually slow after the application has started because  proxy objects are being are created and frame work initializes all the classes that are required to make the WS calls.

A common workaround for this is to have your service expose some stub method which wont do anything) and when your application starts up, call this stub. 
This will create the service proxy objects in the background and the when your app actually makes a call out to the service, everything is ready.

Comment: shouldn't take 10-20 seconds to create some proxy objects.

Comment: It depends from server to server as in our case we are using web-logic and the first call takes 50-60 seconds and when we tried in JBoss it was taking 20-30 seconds. Google for "first WS call are slow" you will  find out a lot of information.